# How to pass ctx to another function when I cant get it on python discord bot

Tags: discord.py, bots

I have already done that google assistant sends message to my text channel and I want that my other bot listen only to my google Assistant bot. I have found a way a little... tricky, by changing the method process_command() to avoid the return when the id of the message is from my google assistant.

I don't think that it is a good solution, and it would only work on my computer and it is working right now, another problem is that the bot must be in a voice channel to work. So I've been thinking, on the function on_message, with startswith("whatever character") to the message.content I can filter the messages of my bot and go directly to the function, but I need the parameter ctx that I don't know how to pass it because on_message the only parameter that it has is "message".
How can I get the ctx from the function on_message? I'm open to new suggestion about how do it on another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `get_context` method

```py
ctx = await bot.get_context(message) # or `client.get_context`
```

### Reference:

- [`Bot.get_context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context)